# initramfs after installing ubuntu server 18.04 with LVM

Tags: server, 18.04, initramfs

I'm working to create a new Ubuntu Server 18.04 template on my local vSphere environment to upload this again to our datacenter.

I downloaded the Ubuntu server 18.04.2 LTS.iso version from their website and during the Filesystem setup I choose for "Use an entire disk and set up LVM" so that I can have the following directory's:

```
/home
/tmp
/usr
/var
/var/log
```

and of course `/`, `/boot` and SWAP

By choosing this option in the Filesystem setup Ubuntu is creating by default a volume group and a LVM that is attached to `/`,
it creates also `/boot` so for me is left to create the other directories as mentioned before.

After this step I select done, and finished the next step and once it asked to remove the installation medium and press enter, it reboots and I get the initramfs screen saying (see picture):

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong or how to fix this?

If you need more information please let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: hi! this all seems a bit outdated what kind of hardware and what kind of memory size workload does your server have? because increases in the performance of the ubuntu system and of hardware as a whole has led to the sort-of deprecation of SWAP. on a 8GB of RAM (again depending on the type of memeory load you expect to have on that server) you will never get any sort of performance increase thanks to swap. So nowadays we generally opt out. Also I personally advise against LVM and instead advise a simple dual mountpoint setup `/` and `/home`.

Comment: Hello, I also tried this in virtual box on my desktop that has 16GB of memory, i5 vPro processor with 500GB of data disk. 

My server is an HP server (ProLiant DL G6), vmware vsphere 6.0, Intel Xeon x5560 8 cpu's x 2,8GHz and 150GB total ram
Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes. ok so to me you do not need SWAP. of course it's up to you if disk space is a plenty that's fine. you are also free to add it at any later time. I just don't think ubuntu 18 will use it much under these contditions.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you exactly mean with running what?

Comment: nevermind it was your previous edit, I too have edited since then. anyways are you open to trying without LVM?

Comment: I tried it now with creating only /home and that works fine. So still I don't understand what I did wrong during the Filesystem setup or does Ubuntu not allow to create more lvm's then it already creates by default? Because the situation that I get looks almost like when you accidentally forgot to change the fstab file after renaming a directory or a VG or LVM.

Comment: that is a good one, I don't know. try simply with `/` and `/home` and LVM?

Comment: and what is the best practice for having other mounts like /tmp, /usr, /var etc?

Comment: that's one of the outdated things I was refferring to along with SWAP : the current best practice is to not have them. they will be part of `/` but having them each in a seperate partition induces headaches with no reward. `/` needs 30GB all future updates/upgrades included and you can give the rest to `/home` which requires much more.

Comment: But there are disadvantage for having only / and /home but I don't remember what they are exactly. Is it not so that when / is full that you can't access the vm but having the dirs separately mounted that you can easy extend them when they are full?

Comment: yes partitions remain resiseable so long as you can boot and this may not be thes case if `/` is too full. listen I personally would only have `/` even for a workplace server. this way all these problems are moot. the only reason people do `/`+`/home` is for easy reinstall (repair = reinstall) without loosing most programs and configs and all the data (because that's on home) but If you don't mind the preparation copy of  all data in order to usher in a full reformat of the drive for a reinstall + programs reinstall, then save yourself some trouble and just go `/`. i

Comment: i'll add an answer. please mark it this will make the question hava more people who can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend first and foremost against :

having all these mountpoints (`/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/var`, `/var/log`, `SWAP`). The moddern popular approach is `/` (30GB) and `/home` (the rest) and that's all. (of course if the BIOS and the OS support UEFI then first comes a 500mb EFI patrition, if you're in LEGACY, ignore this.

(As a personal preference I go `/` alone, but this removes the posibility of salvaging and reusing `/home` on several reinstalls of the OS)

Then I'd recommend agaisnt SWAP. especially in your senatio where your hardware (Intel Xeon x5560 8 cpu's x 2,8GHz and 150GB of RAM) indicates that it'll never see any use.

Lastly I personally recommend against LVM. If you don't *really* need it, you shouldn't care about it. It makes boot much more iffy, and in your case I think the issue came from too many mountpoints + LVM.

of course using it is at your discretion.

Comment: I have an update, I created all mount points that I wanted except /usr and everything went OK. so I can add /usr after the installation manually. But still is strange for me why I can't add them during the installation

Comment: I am clueless as to this. perhaps someone else knows. some core programs install to usr instead of home, maybe this causes problems durring the installation, I don't know.